# Check if (number) plus (number) equals the answer you type

Tags: if-statement, vbscript

Basically I'm trying to make a .vbs file that gives you ten random addition problems. Then, in an input box, you type the answer to the given problem. Everything works except the `If`/`Else` statement that tells you if you are right or wrong. If it says "What is 2 + 2" and I type "4" (without quotations), then it outputs "(You attack) TRIP! POW! ouchy wrong You could've gotten it right IF you typed: 4." Here's the code:

```
msgbox("Starting addition. Press OK to begin.")
dim i
i = 0

Do
  i = i + 1
  'i is for the question timer
  Dim max,min
  max=100 'max random
  min=1 'min random
  dim j, k, l 'part part total

  Randomize
  msgbox("What is") 
  j = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
  msgbox(j)
  msgbox("plus") 
  k = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
  msgbox(k)
  answer = Inputbox("I hope you got all of that... ^_^")
  l = j + k

  if answer = l then
    msgbox("(You attack) BAM! Right on target")
  else
    msgbox("(You attack) TRIP! POW! ouchy wrong")
    msgbox("You could've gotten it right IF you typed:")
    msgbox(l)
  end if
loop until i = 10
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more code satisfying [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Okay, I edited it to show my entire program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in [Comparison Operators (VBScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) reference:

> ... how expressions are compared or what results from the comparison,
>   depending on the underlying subtype:
>  ...
>   *If* one expression is numeric and the other is a string *Then* the numeric expression *is **less** than* the string expression.

```
j = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
k = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)
answer = Inputbox("I hope you got all of that... ^_^" _
  & vbCR & "What is " & j & " plus " & k)
l = j + k
If IsNumeric( answer) then 
  answer = Int( answer)
Else
  answer = l - 1
End If 
if answer = l then
  msgbox("(You attack) BAM! Right on target")
else
  msgbox("(You attack) TRIP! POW! ouchy wrong")
  msgbox("You could've gotten it right IF you typed:")
  msgbox(l)
end if
```